# When they list the income of someone, is it the monthly or yearly income?

Tags: salary, income

When they list the income of someone like [Steve Balmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Ballmer#cite_note-0) ($1,267,670) in wikipedia, is it the monthly or yearly income?

Comment: Yearly! Yearly! Yearly! Yearly!

Comment: This is Mr Balmer's Salary from Microsoft his income from Dividends and other investments is going to be a lot more salary != income

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is typically yearly income.  In Balmer's case Microsoft is a public company and his salary and bonuses are listed in [MSFT's 2010 proxy](http://google.brand.edgar-online.com/displayfilinginfo.aspx?FilingID=7482472-861-263715&type=sect&TabIndex=2&companyid=8528&ppu=%252fdefault.aspx%253fsym%253dMSFT).

Answer (score 3):

In the US, salary discussions are almost always annual. Unless you're talking part time work with varying hours, then hourly makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The income listed are usually yearly salary.